# Centre aligned div, that has text aligned to the left

Tags: html, css

I want that div in the middle of the page, the div should be 561px and the text needs to be left aligned.

```
<div id="notes">
aaaaaaaaa
a
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things. Firstly:

```
#notes { width: 561px; margin: 8 auto; text-align: left; }
```

Secondly, make sure you Webpage has a DOCTYPE declaration (mainly for IE's benefit):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

`margin: 0 auto` is the standard way of centering a *block element*. It's a shorthand syntax. See [8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#mpb-examples) of [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/):

> The 'margin' property is a shorthand
>   property for setting 'margin-top',
>   'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', and
>   'margin-left' at the same place in the
>   style sheet.
>
> If there is only one value, it applies
>   to all sides. If there are two values,
>   the top and bottom margins are set to
>   the first value and the right and left
>   margins are set to the second. If
>   there are three values, the top is set
>   to the first value, the left and right
>   are set to the second, and the bottom
>   is set to the third. If there are four
>   values, they apply to the top, right,
>   bottom, and left, respectively.
>
> ```
> body { margin: 2em }         /* all margins set to 2em */
> body { margin: 1em 2em }     /* top & bottom = 1em, right & left = 2em */
> body { margin: 1em 2em 3em } /* top=1em, right=2em, bottom=3em, left=2em */
> ```

So the `auto` in `margin: 0 auto;` means:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

In this situation the browser will center the block element. IE **won't** do this ***unless*** it is in standards-compliant mode, which you force by providing a DOCTYPE declaration. See [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Comment: @Swingley: Sets the top and bottom margins of the element and the left and right margin to share the remaining width of the parent element between them, essentially centering the element.

Comment: Yes. Google uses simply <doctype html>

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet do:

```
#id {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 561px;
}
```